# Copy and Paste Multiple Regex Search Matches in Atom on OSX

Tags: atom-editor

Given the below text and searching with the regular expression: ^Z\d.*

```
b
Z1a
a
Z2ab
c
Z3abc
d
```

Is it possible to search for the lines starting with Z and copy/paste the resulting into a new text file as

```
Z1a
Z2ab
Z3abc
```

What are the shortcut keys and/or necessary packages?

Comment: If using a terminal is acceptable to you, rather than doing this manually through Atom, then see my answer below. Otherwise, using Atom alone will require manually copying and pasting the results and manually creating the new file.

Answer (score 0):

This would be best achieved from the OSX Terminal app with `grep`, rather than from Atom.

Suppose that your example text is located in a file called `input.txt` and your new file is called `output.txt`, then the following single line will do everything that you need.

```
$ grep '^Z\d.*' input.txt > output.txt
```

In this example, `grep` performs your regular expression search on the input file and then pipes the output to your new file. This doesn't require any copy and paste, nor are there any other intermediary steps.

You can see the output of `grep` by simply removing the pipe to the output file.

```
$ grep '^Z\d.*' input.txt
Z1a
Z2ab
Z3abc
```